# keycloak "error_description": "Missing form parameter: grant_type" error

Tags: keycloak, token-exchange

AM currently trying to do token exchange from google to Keycloak, Now am facing this error `"error_description": "Missing form parameter: grant_type"`.
[postman body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlOz2.png) ****
[content type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws8zE.png)****

This is my configuration in postman.
[Keycloak setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM39U.png)

Comment: Don't you have to also provide the subject_issuer?

Comment: @dreamcrash I have also added the subject_issuer to google, But the result has not changed.

Comment: Posting code as images should be avoided

Answer (score 0):

You should activate Content-Length in Headers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).